# How long are close flags valid

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269799/pythonic-way-to-extract-specific-values-from-a-dictionary-based-on-a-subset-of-k) and while it made perfect sense to me it received three close votes within a relatively short times.  I continued to work on the question and actually received a really useful answer.

My underlying question is - so the close votes are no longer piling on - do the existing close votes expire after some fixed amount of time if the necessary votes needed to close aren't accumulated by that time?

Comment: With that said, I don't know if this is still 100% accurate, as the SE team does occasionally tweak things slightly, but this may help get you started in terms of how and when close votes expire:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/155826

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are rules published on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/155826) that do outline the behavior of the close votes, but it's from 2011 and may not reflect the most up to date version of the close vote rule expiration.  The Stack Exchange team does occasionally tweak this.

This was written by [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood), Stack Exchange co-founder:

> Close votes (and probably reopen votes) only expire after all of these conditions are met:
>
> 4 days have passed since the last close vote.
> The question has more than 100 views.

Also, Animuson points out a [newer version of that question from 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away).

Comment: Here's a newer one: [How do close votes age away?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away)

Answer (score 0):

If the question has since been fixed and the reason that those original reviewers voted to close no longer applies, then it doesn't really matter. It does not hurt you in any way for < 5 close votes to sit there.

Yes, [eventually the close votes will age away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166124/153008), but the exact time frame or criteria according to which this happens is immaterial and hardly worth committing to memory.

If you have fixed the problems, the number of votes will not keep growing. If you have not, then the question will likely be closed. The closure reason will direct your attention to the problem, which can be fixed and the question subsequently re-opened by following the same process.